# How to send a right curly bracket with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Tags: sendkeys, naturallyspeaking

How to send a right curly [bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) (i.e., `}`) with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

MSDN's document on the [`SendKeys` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx) says:

> To specify brace characters, use {{} and {}}.

Sending a left curly bracket (i.e., `{`), works fine with the following advanced scripting command:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "{{}"
End Sub
```

However, when I try to do the same for the right curly bracket (i.e., `}`), it doesn't work:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "{}}"
End Sub
```

Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Advanced Scripting", that made me chuckle a little.

Comment: @Krythic That's because I am using the *professional* version of Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old glitch in Advanced Scripting.

You can use the ASCII code instead:

```
Sub Main
SendKeys Chr(125), True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just `SendKeys "}"`?  That works in DNS13 and above.

Comment: @pgilm this may or may not work depending on your keyboard layout.  It may be only rarely a problem, but still it may occur. I faced the same thing a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape a right brace by itself, just do:

```
SendKeys "}"
```

But if you want to send a whole "braced" expression, it gets more complicated.  For example, to use a script to send "{Esc}" you need this:

```
SendKeys "{{}Esc}"  ' {Esc}
```

Hth,

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed trying to send a braced expression :) I hadn't noticed that for a single brace `SendKeys "}"` was working.

Answer (score 0):

One inconvenient way to circumvent this issue: going through the clipboard, as shown below.

```
Sub Main
    originalClipboard = Clipboard
    Clipboard("{")
    SendKeys "^v"
    Wait(0.2)
    Clipboard(originalClipboard)
End Sub
```

Comment: That is not necessary, though.  Why trouble yourself with escaping the right brace?  Just `SendKeys "}"` should do it.